# Fetch records as batches in Postgres using a cursor

Tags: postgresql

I need to fetch data as 100 of records batches from a PostgresSQL table. I have tried the following function,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fetch_compare_prices(n integer)
RETURNS SETOF varchar AS $$
DECLARE
  curs CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM compareprices LIMIT n;
  row  RECORD;
BEGIN
  open curs;
  LOOP
    FETCH FROM curs INTO row;
    EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
    return next row.deal_id;
  END LOOP;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I ran this query to get results from the above function.`select fetch_compare_prices(100);` But this gives me only same 100 records always. Is there a way to fetch 100 records as batches using a cursor.

also with this `return next row.deal_id;` statement I can only return just the deal_id but no other columns. Is there a way to get all the columns/row?

Also, It should work like when I run `select fetch_compare_prices(100);` this for the 1st time, it should return first 100 rows, when I run it 2nd time, it should give rows from 100 to 200(next 100). What's the correct usage of cursor to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by wrapping it in a function?  Why not just have the client declare and use the cursor directly.

Comment: didn't know about such a thing. I'm pretty new to this thing. Could you please send me some references or guide me? Thank you very much

Comment: Client cursors are documented here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-declare.html